# IE10 - text-align: center is aligning to the right

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, text-align

I am using `text-align: center` in a div to align a section heading. For some reason in IE 9/10 it is aligning to the right. When I comment it out, it goes back to being centered.

In Chrome/FF/Safari it works just fine. I don't have this issue with any other sections, so am guessing it has something to do with it being nested inside another div.

```
<h3 class="sub-section-heading light teal-ts">Complete Ingredient List:</h3>
    <div id="ingredient-list">
        Aloe barbadensis (Organic Aloe) Juice,
    </div>
```

```css
.sub-section-heading {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'pf_regular';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some source code that isn't working please?

Comment: Sorry about that hit submit too fast: Code up n link to Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jstone/KN748/1/

Comment: It looks the same to me in ie10 and in Chrome.